# Sort using child field in a parent - child SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

What is the best way for me to sort with this soql:

```
Parent Object = PO
Child Object = CO

Select PO_Field1, PO_Field2, PO_Field3, PO_Field4, (SELECT CO_Field1,
CO_Field2, CO_Field3, CO_Field4 FROM ChildObject order by CO_Field3) FROM 
ParentObject Order by PO_Field1
```

The result of the above code is not consistent (and not sorted) when displayed in Lightning Component, which shows data per month.

my main target is to have a result that is order by with `CO_Field3` .

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You say you want to show "Data per month" but then you say your main target is sorting by CO_Field3.  What is CO_Field3?  Please edit your post to describe exactly how you want the sort order to appear.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to query on child object instead of parent object. You can access parent fields using relationship field and you can sort your records using child's field which is what your main target is i.e. to have the results that is sorted by CO_Field3

```
Parent Object = PO
Child Object = CO

SELECT PO__r.PO_Field1, PO__r.PO_Field2, PO__r.PO_Field3, PO__r.PO_Field4,
        CO_Field1, CO_Field2, CO_Field3, CO_Field4 FROM ChildObject 
        ORDER BY CO_Field3
```

Comment: it will need alot of code changes in my part which is what i am trying to avoid. is there any easier way that we could use the existing query?

Comment: Hi @MRianne Can you please explain in detail, what issues are you facing when you say "The result of the above code is not consistent (and not sorted) when displayed in Lightning Component"